# Why is reading an array within a lamda expression resulting in an error?

Tags: java, arrays

In the two examples, the first compiles without error, but the second results in the error "Local variable values defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final" where I attempt to call assertThrows.  Why?  I am not modifying the array in either case.  In fact I copy  and pasted the assertThrows line from the first example into the second example and only changed the index used.  I'm struggling to understand how to fix the error.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import java.util.Arrays;

class ArrayTests {

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Test

    void TestArrayException() {
        int[] values = new int[5];
        assertEquals(0, values[0]);
        // here I am reading values within a lamda expression and it works without  compiler error.
        assertThrows(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class, () -> { int value = values[17]; });
    }

    /**
     * Since arrays can't be resized copyOf can build a new copy with the new length
     *  truncating or increasing the size of the array with default values.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Test
    void TestCopyOf() {
        int [] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        values = Arrays.copyOf(values, 7);
        assertEquals(values.length, 7);
        assertEquals(values[5], 0);
        assertEquals(values[6], 0);

        values = Arrays.copyOf(values, 2);
        assertEquals(values.length, 2);
        assertEquals(values[0], 1);
        assertEquals(values[1], 2);
        // error occurs in the next line accessing the values array.
        assertThrows(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class, () -> { int value = values[3]; });
    }
}
```

Comment: The reson is that you reasign values to a second array. now in the lambda "the" value of "values" is kept even after the method exited. for that you need to ensure, that the object referenced isn't garbage collected (which happens if you reasign values again). To work arround that you can use a sencond (semi-)final varible and use that(with the sole purpose to serve as an anchor that prevents garbagecollection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that a lambda is just syntactic sugar for creating an anonymous inner class implementing (in your case) `IntSupplier` (resulting in a class named e.g. `ArrayTests$27`).

So the rules for inner classes apply. `ArrayTest$27` instances can't access the local variables from any currently-executing method of `ArrayTest`, just like any other class can't do that.

So, when your lambda seems to access the `values` array (it's just a clever illusion!), in reality the array from `values` gets passed into the (invisible) constructor of `ArrayTests$27`, and gets stored as a hidden field of that class, and it's that field that the lambda code really accesses.

Of course, this copy of `values` doesn't change when you re-assign the `values` variable itself, so this would break the illusion of accessing the original `values` variable. To the language designers, keeping up the illusion seemed important, so they allowed "access" only to variables that don't change - originally only those marked final, later also allowing those without any re-assignment, even without the keyword.

Coming back to your code example:

- In the first method, you don't re-assign `values`, so the compiler can keep up the illusion with the copying trick.
- In the second method, you do re-assign `values`, so the compiler refrains from keeping up the illusion. In theory, it would be possible to keep it up, as you don't modify `values` after the moment you create the lambda. But that's not part of the language specification.

Answer (score 2):

The `assertThrows` is checking that you are using a final or effectively final variable (that cannot be modified). 
But in your code, you reassign the variable `values`.
You should just use an another one:

```
@Test
    void TestCopyOf() {
        int [] values = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

        int [] firstArray = Arrays.copyOf(values, 7);
        assertEquals(firstArray.length, 7);
        assertEquals(firstArray[5], 0);
        assertEquals(firstArray[6], 0);

        int [] secondArray = Arrays.copyOf(values, 2);
        assertEquals(secondArray.length, 2);
        assertEquals(secondArray[0], 1);
        assertEquals(secondArray[1], 2);

        assertThrows(IndexOutOfBoundsException.class, () -> { int value = secondArray[3]; });
    }
```

Comment: It's strange, but code works even if first array will be replaced by `values = Arrays.copyOf(values, 7);` - why?

Comment: I'm not following you.  I thought that the ideas is that it can't be modified within the lambda.  According to https://karims.in/java-8-assigning-variable-inside-lambda-foreach-c73720f1860f the example shown indicates that it is a problem to modify something in the lamba.

Comment: @Bor Laze it appears that Java has a restriction that one cannot even read a non-final variable within a lamba.  I find that to be a very strange restriction.  Most  examples explaining the concept who something being modified within the lambda.  firstArray can be changed to values because values is not being accessed in the lambda.  The issue seems to be that a lambda expression cannot even capture something from the enclosing method that might be modified elsewhere in the method.  I don't remember any kind of restriction like that in C# or C++ but maybe I just forgot about it.

Comment: @shawn1874 see my answer explaining the inner workings of lambda.

Comment: Thank you.  This was also a helpful answer as it provided example code.